# How to show the pdf file from local folder to replace particular dom content in webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I have a html page

```
<body>
<header class="app-header panel-heading">Sample</header>
<div class="app-main-container">
   <div class="app-left-panel col-xs-3">some content here</div>
   <div class="app-right-panel col-xs-3">some content here</div>      
</div>
</body>

<div class="panel panel-info"id="scrollbar" style="height:100%;overflow-y:scroll">
              <div class="panel-heading" style="padding-bottom: 20px;padding-right: 8px;">
                <h3 class="panel-title" id="content-heading"></h3>
                  <div class="dropdown pull-right" style="margin-top: -1.5em;">
                      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                        selectModule
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                      </button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="app-pdf-list">
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="./pdfs/Module1.pdf">Module 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="./pdfs/Module2.pdf">Module 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="./pdfs/Module3.pdf">Module 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="./pdfs/Module4.pdf">Module 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="./pdfs/Module5.pdf">Module 5</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body content-holder" id="content-holder">

              </div>
```

on anchor link click , the pdf has to be loaded in the "div#app-main-container"
but the pdf is getting open as new page.

```
$('ul#app-pdf-list li').click(function (event) {
var pdfLink = event.target.getAttribute('name');
if (pdfLink) {
    $.get(pdfLink, function (data) {
        $("#app-main-container").empty();
        $("#app-main-container").append(data);
    });
    //('#app-main-container').html('<object type="application/pdf" data=' + pdfLink + '></object>');
}
});
```

How to load data in the main-container by replacing the existing the content.

Comment: What do you mean by _load data_? Are you trying to load the pdf and use some kind of the preview to display its content?

Comment: show the pdf file in the div#app-main-container

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=display+pdf+in+html

Comment: I referred and did the above coding but still I couldnt solve the problem.

Comment: Is there any change in the above code ?